# Adding item to Square via SquareConnect PHP API -- 'category' and 'fees' defs being excluded

Tags: php, square-connect

SquareConnect API newbie here.

I am attempting to add an item to Square using the PHP method:

```
$api_instance = new SquareConnect\Api\V1ItemsApi();
$body = new \SquareConnect\Model\V1Item($request_body);
$result = $api_instance->createItem($location_id, $body);
```

My request_body definition:

```
$request_body = array( 
  "name" => "**ITEM NAME**",
  "description" => "**ITEM DESCRIPTION**",
  "category" => array(
      "id" => "**CATEGORY ID**",
      "name" => "**CATEGORY NAME**"
  ),
  "variations" => array( 
      array( 
          "name" => "**VARIATION NAME**", 
          "sku" => "**SKU**",
          "pricing_type" => "FIXED_PRICING", 
          "price_money" => array( 
              "currency_code" => "USD", 
              "amount" => "**AMOUNT**"
          ) 
      ) 
  ),
  "fees" => array(
    "enabled" => "1",
    "name" => "Sales Tax",
    "rate" => "0.0775",
    "calculation_phase" => "FEE_SUBTOTAL_PHASE",
    "adjustment_type" => "TAX",
    "inclusion_type" => "ADDITIVE",
    "type" => "US_SALES_TAX"
  )
);
```

The item and variation data are being added to Square, but the "category" and "fees" definitions are not being included.  As a result the item is ending up in flat space, which requires me to log into the main Square interface, add the item to the appropriate category AND set its tax information.  I do not want to have to take these additional steps if they can be avoided.

The tax information in the "fees" section is taken verbatim from the definitions found in items added via the Square interface.  I have confirmed and re-confirmed that the category id and category name match those of the desired category.  I also tried replacing the "category" array with a simple "category_id" => "CATEGORY ID" definition.  Same result.

Can anyone assist?  Also, if there is a better method for adding an item to Square via the API, please let me know!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Part one, categories**

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#post-items) about specifying a item category during item creation:

[image: category docs]

You are specifing an array:

```
  "category" => array(
      "id" => "**CATEGORY ID**",
      "name" => "**CATEGORY NAME**"
  ),
```

you should instead be using a string:

```
  "category" => "**CATEGORY ID**",
```

**Part two, fees**

If you look again at the docs, you won't see any reference to fees in V1 items create. That is because you cannot create a fee with that endpoint. Instead you should [create a new fee](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#post-fees). You can see some sample code here: https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/docs/Api/V1ItemsApi.md#createfee

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
As I had mentioned in my initial post, I tried using the category_id = (string).  I also tried using just "category" as you had in your example.  No luck.

Comment: As for fees, the fees for my location have already been created.  I just need to associate items with fees.  Or fees with items.

Comment: You need to put in the actual category id. Please edit your answer with your exact request.

Comment: Yet another issue along the same lines.  I am not able to define the item as PUBLIC:
"visibility" => "PUBLIC"
What is particularly weird is that when I print_r the result of the createItem command, the item shows up as PUBLIC... but then when I do a subsequent listItems it is PRIVATE.

Comment: The request_body is the same as shown above but...
  "category" => array(
      "id" => "**CATEGORY ID**",
      "name" => "**CATEGORY NAME**"
  ),
...has been replaced with...
    "category_id" => "**CATEGORY ID**"
No luck.  It is not associating the item with the category.

Comment: This page shows an example of an addItem request (via JSON).
https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/connect-examples/v1/php/item-management.php
Interestingly, the fields that I am trying unsuccessfully to set are not included in this example.  Is it possible that those fields cannot be set by this method?

Comment: Categories are an optional field. You should use an actual id, not the string `"CATEGORY ID"`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing.  I was using **CATEGORY ID** in this post so as not to show the actual category ID, which is VLO35J... (etc).

Comment: Got the answer to the 'fees' issue here.  The solution works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693968/assigning-fees-to-an-item-on-creation?rq=1
I am going to apply the same logic to 'category' assignment.  Will keep you posted on that.
Still not sure what's going on with 'visibility'.

Comment: Still no luck with being able to add item:category.  Tried multiple variations of the same method that was used to add fees:
https://connect.squareup.com/v1/{{location_id}}/items/{{item_id}}/categories/{{category_id}}
...as well as doing an update as shown on this page:
https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/connect-examples/v1/php/item-management.php
No luck.
I am also not able to change visibility to PUBLIC.  Might these two issues be related?

Comment: seems unlikely, but if you would like to debug more it might be easier in our slack community https://squ.re/slack

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to focus on the category_id since you seemed to have figured out the "fees" issue based on the comments.

I just used this as test code, and the category was set successfully:

```
  $items_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\V1ItemsApi();

  $body = array(
    "name" => "Test Item",
    "category_id" => "YFIHMKYXNFJ7TE5FRBWQAGU6",
    "variations" => array(
        array(
        "name" => "Small",
        "pricing_type" => "FIXED_PRICING",
        "price_money" => array(
            "amount" => 100,
            "currency_code" => "USD"
        )
    ))
  );

  $result = $items_api->createItem($location_id, $body);
  echo $result;
```

Location_id was created earlier, but everything else is there.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately, for whatever reason, it just isn't working for me to set the category_id via V1ItemsApi.
However, it does work when I create the item via CatalogApi, so I'm using that process instead.